# Can we use other object than self for button’s target?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Instead of self can we use another object with addTarget in this code:

```
[nextMonthButton addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(showFollowingMonth) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If yes what are those objects?

Comment: Read the documentation, it tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be any object, but the button does not retain that object when you add it as a target, so your object will have to last around for as long as the button is around, and know to release itself when the button is deallocated. This is usually hard to do, unless that object is the controller of a view containing the button, or some object that belongs to such a controller.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

The other object just has to respond to showFollowingMonth so typically it will be a custom class you have created.

Answer (score 0):

It can be pretty much any object that is alive and is able to respond to the given selector.

However, for actions with a visual feedback where you need to manipulate the views, staying in the controller will be the best strategy anyway.